# How to calculate the Message Integrity Code(MIC) with Python?

Tags: python, encryption, wifi

Recently, i'm trying to calculate MIC manually in Python to verify the MIC value in the Message 2 of the 4-way handshake because when i try connection process between the router and the WIFI module stops at the message 2 each time.

As i'm using WPA2

```
mic = hmac.new(ptk[0:16].encode("ascii"), payload, hashlib.sha1).hexdigest()[:32]
```

payload is the whole part of 802.1X Authentication with the MIC replaced by 0x00.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4vok.png)

To calculate ptk, i use PRF-384

```
ptk = customPRF384(pmk, pke, key_data)

def customPRF384(key, A, B):
    blen = 48
    i = 0
    R = ''
    while i <= ((blen * 8 + 159) / 160):
        hmacsha1 = hmac.new(key, (str(A) + chr(0x00) + str(B) + chr(i)).encode("ascii"), hashlib.sha1)
        i += 1
        R = R + hmacsha1.hexdigest()
    return R[:blen]
```

with

```
pke = "Pairwise key expansion"
key_data = min(mac_ap, mac_cl) + max(mac_ap, mac_cl) + min(anonce,snonce) + max(anonce,snonce)
```

and

```
pmk = PBKDF2(psk, ssid, 4096).read(32)
```

(i'm little confused about the iteration, is that fixed?)

However, with this methode, i'm not able to calculate the right MIC.
If some of you could find some errors, i'll appreciate that!

Comment: Could you please provide more context, a traceback of any errors, and be more specific about what might be wrong with your code or where you are confused?

Comment: Hello, there is no evident error in the code, but i cannot get the correct MIC as i see in the Wireshark. So i'm confused about whether this is the right method to calculate the MIC since the connection always stops at the message 2, i think maybe there is something wrong in MIC